# PHP not receiving value/data from $_GET["_escaped_fragment_"]

Tags: php, ajax, google-crawlers

I have been trying to use/get the values from `$_GET["_escaped_fragment_"]` in PHP in WAMP SERVER but it doesn't seem to work.

PHP Code:

```
$values = $_GET['_escaped_fragment_'];
if($values) {
    echo "Values: ".$values;
}
```

JQuery Code:

```
   $(function() {
        $(window).hashchange(function() {
            if(window.location.hash) {
                var url = window.location.hash.split("#!");
                carregar(url[1]);
            }
        });
        $(window).hashchange();
    });

    function carregar(url){
        $('#container').load('/'+url+".php",function(){
        });
    }
```

HTML Code:

```
<a href="/#!home">> Home</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="/#!contato">> Contato</a><br>

<div id="container">
    <?php
        if($values) {
            include $values.".php";
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Robots.txt

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
```

So, if I click a link (home for ex.) it will be: `localhost/#!home`, and it does loads the content from `home.php` which display my home content.

**Problem** the PHP `$_GET["_escaped_fragment_"]` doesn't get any values, even when I force to load the page(writing in the url and hitting Enter)

My Wamp Version:

Apache Version: 2.4.9

PHP Version: 5.5.12

MySQL Version: 5.6.17

Comment: What do you see if you do `print_r($_REQUEST)` do you see the variable then?

Comment: What do you expect to be in the `$_GET["_escaped_fragment_"]`?

Comment: @AdamT No, I get this: `Array ( ) `

Comment: @holpducki can you post the contents/ code of your HTML form?

Comment: @MichaelCoxon I know Im missing something, but I don't know WHAT!? Im expecting the `url`/`link` from the <a> tag

Comment: @AdamT I don't have a form, I have links e.g.`<a href="/#!home"..`

Comment: Well, you aren't appending `?_escaped_fragment=blah` to the url in your jQuery load method so it won't be sent server-side.

Comment: As @MichaelCoxon mentioned, If you're relying on a $_GET variable, it should have the variable and value as part of its query string URI.  For example, mysite.com/index.php?var=3 . You should obtain value = '3' if you do `$_GET['var']`

Comment: @MichaelCoxon but the `?_espaced_fragment=blah` would the the "ugly-url". How do I send the "pretty-url" e.g.`#!home` and the "ugly-url" only to the server-side?

Comment: @AdamT I understand what you want to say Adam, but this `#!url-variable` is another way. Have a look at: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification

Comment: See my answer.. it is untested, but you should get the gist of what I mean.. since it is an AJAX call the `window.loaction` won't change

Comment: If you don't want users seeing the ugly URL, you need to send POST instead of GET

Comment: @AdamT I understand, but have a look at the link I've commented and you will understand what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from my comments... You will need to do something like....

```
$(function() {
    $(window).hashchange(function() {
        if(window.location.hash) {
            var url = window.location.hash.split("#!");
            var realUrl = '/' + url[1] + 
                ".php?_escaped_fragment_=/" + encodeURIComponent(window.location.hash);

            $('#container').load(realUrl, function(){
               // do stuff when finished
            });
        }
    });
    $(window).hashchange();
});
```

Comment: Hmm, nice thinking, BUT have a look at this: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification

Comment: After visiting the link...Sorry, my mistake, by `ugly url` I thought you were describing it as ugly in appearance as opposed to the Google documentation.

Comment: @AdamT No problem, so as I said previously, I can load the page and etc, I just can get the `values` in the php code because im missing something to send the values to the `server-side` I guess.

Comment: @MichaelCoxon I still can't get the variable in PHP as im Loading the page im sending the variable/value and not the original one.

Comment: @holpducki Hey man, yeah this is just how Google does it when it crawls your site. You still have to program in all the heavy lifting - there is no built in magic for this.

Comment: I was missing the `_` at the end of the key.. fix that and try again

Comment: @MichaelCoxon Still doesn't work. I have been looking to some websites that uses this way of pages, and I haven't seen it anywhere where they send the `_escaped_fragment_` only the normal page `#!page/etc`

Comment: They won't send the fragment as there is no need to. This is something Google does when indexing your 'AJAX based' site, so that it can index 'static' pages. Google's bot doesn't run the JavaScript on a page so they implemented sending a ?_escaped_fragment_ to your index page with the hash fragment as the value so that you can then program in the ability to return your content so it can be indexed.

Comment: @MichaelCoxon I have a code from a made website with the exact codes(which I can't see where they send the `?_escaped_fragment_`) and also happen to have the `$_GET["..` to receive the values, but I still can't understand how it is made, even though I have the full code of their website.

Comment: I have added the `encodeURIComponent` method to stop the browser stripping the hash. But I don't think you fully understand the purpose of this. You only need to handle it on your PHP side, you do not need it in your JavaScript. Re-read that link you sent me. Google's Webmaster guide is just so you can make your site indexable - it is not a codex.

Comment: Not fully answered but it did help. Thank you